# How to identify an entity has quick create form enabled or not by Javascript?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2016

I have some code below by which I am opening quick create form for entities if enabled but if not enabled I want to open in new window. I need to identify the entity has enabled quick create form or not on definition and how to do it by Javascript?

```
var entityFormOptions = {};
entityFormOptions["entityName"] = "contact";
entityFormOptions["useQuickCreateForm"] = true;

// will make it true if quick create form not enabled
entityFormOptions["openInNewWindow"] = false;

// Set default values for the Contact form 
var formParameters = {}; 

// Open the form. 
Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions, formParameters).then( function (success) { console.log(success); }, function (error) { console.log(error); });
```

Comment: So what’s the experience from the above code if there is no QC form or QC not enabled?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution, I can find `IsQuickCreateEnabled` through this api request:

```
[organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/EntityDefinitions
```